# Java : one lock per method per object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I'm building a webcrawler and it has 2 main feature wich are both executed as threads :
-The fetcher (crawl a website and separate links from files store both of them into the database).
-The downloader (download files based on their url returned by the fetcher).

I've an object `WebSite` wich include everything I want to know about a website. Now I want to manipulate my database to change the status of a link from **waiting** to **fetching** then to **fetched**. The same goes for files from **waiting** to **downloading** then to **downloaded**.

To prevent a `Fetcher` to fetch a link that has been chosen by another fetcher I've done this function inside my `WebSite` object :

```
public synchronized String[] getNextLink(){
    //Return the next link from database that has visited set to 0 then change it to -1 to say that it's in-use.
}
```

And I've done the same for my `Downloaders` with this function :

```
public synchronized String getNextFile(){
    //Return the next file from database that has downloaded set to 0 then change it to -1 to say that it's downloading
}
```

Both method are inside my `WebSite` object since if 2 Fetchers are working with different websites they cannot Select the same row inside my database (same goes for downloaders). But both function can be called at the same time because `Fetchers` never select a **file** and `Downloaders` never select a **link**.

Now **synchronized** is using a single lock (per object) so both of my methods cannot be called at the same time. Is there another keyword to use **one lock per method per object** ? Or do I need to code it ?

Comment: Why do you even need synchronized? Shouldn't you make sure that every `WebSite` is being processed by a single `Downloader` and a single `Fetcher`?

Comment: I want multiples downloader to use a same Website to download multiples files coming from it at the same time. And same goes to Fetcher to crawl the website faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of applying the `synchronized` keyword to whole methods, which implicitly uses `this` as a lock-object, you can use two independent lock objects (and *any* object can be used as a lock-object in Java) within the methods. Each lock object will be independent of others:

```
private final Object fetcherMutex = new Object();
private final Object downloaderMutex = new Object();

public String[] getNextLink(){
    synchronized (fetcherMutex) { /* ...  */ }
}

public String[] getNextFile(){
    synchronized (downloaderMutex) { /* ...  */ }
}
```

Comment: Since both my methods are inside an object isn't it faster to just create 2 locks inside my object and to deal with them myself than instantiate 2 objects that will have a lock provided by the JVM ?

Comment: To prevent accidents, you should declare the locks as final ie. final Object fetcherMutex = new Object();

Comment: @Palamino thanks - added `private` & `final` modifiers

Comment: @naurel those two locks would be declared inside your class, just as you suggest. All java objects can be used as locks, regardless of whether you do so or not - you do not pay any extra price to "create an object that will be used as a lock" vs "create a lock".